Why Npgsql drop temporary table on error inside a BeginRawBinaryCopyAsync?
I have created a temporary table using an Npgsql command, and if there is an error in my code, I cannot find my temporary table afterward! I know that PostgreSQL does not drop temporary tables within the connection, but only when the connection is closed. Here is a sample test code:
      try {
          //Create a connection string
          var connectionString_log = new NpgsqlConnectionStringBuilder
          {
              Host = "127.0.0.1",
              Database = "bracciniRRSNET",
              Username = "dba",
              Password = "sql",
              Port = 5432,
              Pooling = false,
              ApplicationName = "NewRRSNpgsqlClient", 
              IncludeErrorDetail = true
          }.ConnectionString;
          // Create and open a connection
          var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString_log);
          {
              connection.Open();
              var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
              var command = new NpgsqlCommand("", connection, transaction:transaction);
              command.CommandText = @"CREATE TEMP TABLE temp_users(
                                          user_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
                                          username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                                          email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
                                      )  ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;INSERT INTO temp_users (username, email) VALUES ('Alice', 'alice@example.com');
                                        INSERT INTO temp_users (username, email) VALUES ('Bob', 'bob@example.com');";
              command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Create temporary table

              //Now load table data on a memory stream
              var sql_copy = $"COPY delstory to STDout BINARY;";
              command.CommandText = sql_copy;


              byte[] buffer = new byte[100 * 1024 * 1024];
              MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

              using (var outStream = await connection.BeginRawBinaryCopyAsync(sql_copy))
              {
                  int bytesRead;

                  while ((bytesRead = await outStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                  {
                      memoryStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                  }

              }
              memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
              //Now copy from stdin binary on the same table so do a duplicate key error
              try
              {
                              
                  var copy = $"COPY delstory from  STDin BINARY";
                  command.CommandText = copy;  
                  using (var outStream = await connection.BeginRawBinaryCopyAsync(copy))
                  {

                      int bytesRead;
                      while ((bytesRead = memoryStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                      {
                          await outStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                      }

                      outStream.Write(buffer);
                  }
              }
              catch (Exception ex)
              {   
                  if (ex.Message.Contains("23505:")) // Duplicate key
                  {
                      try
                      {
                          transaction.Commit(); //Close blocked transaction
                          transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
                          command = new NpgsqlCommand("", connection, transaction: transaction);
                          command.CommandText = "select count(*) from temp_users;";
                          var reader = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync(); //ERROR temp_users table not found!
                          reader.Read();
                          Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                      }
                      catch (Exception ex2)
                      {
                          Console.WriteLine(ex2.Message);
                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      } 
      catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

Output:
42P01: relation "temp_users" does not exist

Where is my mistake ?
Why the table is out ?

I have resolved the issue: a commit command is needed after creating the table. I had forgotten to include it, so the temporary table was dropped when the transaction was aborted
